# pthread_mutex_lock called on a destroyed mutex

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

When i try to run my app it got crashed and gives the error shown in the image[pthread_mutex_lock called on a destroyed mutex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTp25.png)

I try to run the app but it got crashed[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xsTW.png)

Comment: Presumably you tried to lock a destroyed mutex. A [mcve] would help in figuring out why (most of us aren't psychic, and need actual code in order to help).